# Cannot get response headers into JSON format

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, python-requests, request-headers

I am making a call to a third-party vendor my company works with, I am trying to send a request and receive my session API token. The problem is, the session id value I need is returned through the response headers. I can see it come back but I cannot get it as a JSON to parse through later.

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic madeUpKey'}

response = requests.get('theThirdPartyURL/api/login', headers=headers, verify=false)

data = response.headers
```

*If I just print data here and don't run the below line I get a string that looks like a JSON with the values I want*

```
data=data.json()
```

I then get this error: `AttributeError: 'CaseInsensitiveDict' object had no attribute 'json'`

I have tried everything on StackOverflow and have not had any luck.

I have also tried `json.dumps(dict(response.headers)))` and a few other suggestions.

Comment: What was the error for ```json.dumps(dict(response.headers)))```?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that response.headers is of type:

```
type(data) == requests.structures.CaseInsensitiveDict
```

which is not serializable.

Not sure about how you want to save your data to "parse through later", but you could use dict() and save it to a file.
This is what works for me:

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com')

with open("file1.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(dict(response.headers), file)
```